# How to make a protocol that declares a property of a protocol type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to leverage protocols and extensions in Swift, but am getting a compile error I can't make sense of.

If I declare two protocols that define a Shape like this:

```
protocol Shape {
  var sides : Int { get }
  var fill : Fill { get }
}

protocol Fill {
  var color : UIColor { get }
}
```

Now to implement this, I define two structs one for a Square, and the other for a solid fill. Like this:

```
struct SolidFill : Fill {
  var color : UIColor
}

struct Square : Shape {
  var sides : Int = 4
  var fill : SolidFill = SolidFill(color: UIColor.blackColor())
}
```

I receive a compile error "Type 'Square' does not conform to protocol 'Shape'". If I force the type of fill to be fill like `var fill : Fill` the compile error goes away. Why can't I have Square specify a more specific type for fill, then what the protocol allows?

I realize that for this particular example, I could change things to not use this pattern by using an Enum for fill or reworking something else. I just want to know why I can't have fill be a type that conforms to the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Because it wouldn't make sense.

Before you start writing code that conforms to protocols, you need to think about your protocols and realize that in a normal use case (and the way that your protocols should be designed), code will be written only with knowledge of the protocol and with zero knowledge of any specific class or struct which implements the protocol.

So, it does make sense for the `Fill` protocol to have other protocols that inherit from it, such as `SolidFill` and perhaps `StripedFill`.

Let's go ahead and add the `StripedFill` protocol to your example.  Now let's look at your `Square` struct and see why it doesn't implement the `Shape` protocol, which in part requires having a `Fill` property.

```
struct Square : Shape {
  var sides : Int = 4
  var fill : SolidFill = SolidFill(color: UIColor.blackColor())
}
```

The only thing we can assign to `Square`'s `fill` property are things which implement the `SolidFill` protocol.  But the `Shape` protocol requires that our shape be able to assign to a property called `fill` anything which conforms to the `Fill` protocol.  And in the case where we also have a protocol called `StripedProtocol` which inherits from the `Fill` protocol, that would include objects that implement that protocol (whether or not they also implement the `SolidFill` protocol).

But your `Square` class doesn't allow for this.  Your `Square` class only allows for one specific child of `Fill` and its descendants, but not its sibling... and the exclusion of `SolidFill`'s potential siblings is why you can't do what you're trying to do.

What you can do however is this:

```
struct Square: Shape {
    var sides: Int = 4
    var fill: Fill = SolidFill(color: UIColor.blackColor())
}
```

So in this case, we're still definitely assigning a `SolidFill` to our `Square`, but we're still allowing for the `fill` property to match what it defined in the protocol and allowing for `SolidFill`'s siblings to be assigned to the `fill` property.

Answer (score 0):

With only a getter it may be theoretically OK but if there was a setter it would definitely not fulfil the protocol as someone may try to set a different object that fulfils the protocol.

If you think it is sufficiently valuable you could raise a radar requesting it for get only vars but you are probably better working around it.

You could do this:

```
struct Square : Shape {
  var sides : Int = 4
  var fill : Fill { solidFill }
  private var solidFill = SolidFill(color: UIColor.blackColor())
}
```